# Unique and catch-all deep link

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have a reasonably simple question which I cannot seem to find the solution to. I have an Android app with multiple activities. I want to form specific deep links to specific activities as well as direct all other deep links to a "catch-all" type activity.

This is my **manifest:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".views.activity1">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:scheme="domain"
            android:host="specificPlace" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".views.activity2">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:scheme="domain"
            android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So what I want is the following:

`domain://specificPlace` -> deep links to activity1.

`domain://` -> deep links to activity2

`domain://random` -> deep links to activity2

`domain://somewhereElse` -> deep links to activity2

Right now domain:// anything is resolving to activity2.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`<intent-filter>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element) supports an integer [`priority` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element#priority). By default, this has a value of `0`, so you could set a *negative* priority on the "catch-all" filter to make sure it runs after all the others:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="-1">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:scheme="domain"
        android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have not tried this myself, but it seems like it should work. The part I'm not sure about is whether or not the `priority` attribute handles negative values. If it does not, you could *instead* put a positive priority on all of the non-"catch-all" filters:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:scheme="domain"
        android:host="specificPlace" />
</intent-filter>
```